# Best way to temporary store user form data, for form resubmission

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, cookies

Currently building out a form that pushes data to a third-party client. After pushing said form data I get a reply back from the third-party server saying something along the lines of 'invalid / valid' data. **If valid** all is perfect in the world and I alert the user with a confirmation message. **If invalid** I would like to key back the values said user inputted back into the form to further expedient the process of form re-submission.

What I'm looking for here is what would be the best / most secure resource to utilize storing this temporary data to key back into the form? Cookie? Database (then clear the database)? Some kind of global variable?

(ps. This is a pretty basic form Name, Email, Address, CC. I don't plan to store CC information in anything! This seems to be a accident waiting to happen if I did, unless someone has experience with storing/clearing such sensitive data!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use jquery and ajax? You don't have to store the data as the page won't reload, it just hangs out in the form waiting for the processing to be done and a success/failure message or function is run.

Comment: I'd say cookies of if you are not expected to reload the page during the transmit you may use a memoization pattern in javascript storing the values in an object.

Comment: Why do you need to store the data anywhere? Just redisplay the form with all the submitted values entered as defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a SESSION if you would like to store the data on the server side. The advantages are:
1. it is compatible with any cookie enabled browser. 
2. You can clear the session data once the user has closed down the browser. This is not always the case with cookies (unless you set it that way).

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5 webstorage pretty easily if you plan to work on IE8+

The supported list is pretty comprehensive http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: HTML5 storage has nothing to do with IE.

Comment: Only that it will not be supported on IE7.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: indeed, but it's usually a given that other browser vendors will support it long before IE does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to save the form data?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using AJAX:

1. User enters form data
2. User clicks "Send" button
3. JS prevents the normal submission of the form, and makes an AJAX connection to your php file, with the form.
4. Your php file validates it and sends the response
5. JS gets the response and shows an appropriate message to the user.

To learn how to use AJAX, go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer doesn't explain any way of storing form data temporally, but if using AJAX there's no need to do so, since the page isn't reloaded.